# Adding a reference, can't use it

Tags: c#, xna

I add my second Project in the solution to my first project as a reference. I select "Projects" in the Add Reference window. The project is called Tile_Engine.
I write this:

```
using Tile_Engine;
```

but it's not found. Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbJE5.png

The error I'm receving is
*Error  2   The type or namespace name 'Tile_Engine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Comment: Is the namespace name "Tile_Engine"?? You can add the image directly in question without giving a link to it.

Comment: Thank you! I always remove the namespace { } when I add files, I didn't know what they were used for.

Answer (score 0):

Check the build properties of your project and check the Target Framework.
This issues happens with ".NET Client profile". Try again if you changed your target framework from e.g. ".NET 4.0 Client Profile" to ".NET 4.0".

Comment: Both are for .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, Tile_Engine is a Class Library and the game is Windows Application.